# Python Pandas: Rerange data from vertical to horizontal

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I would like to transform a data frame using pandas.

**Old-Dataframe:**

| Person-ID | Reference-ID | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Max |
| 2 | 1 | Kevin |
| 3 | 1 | Sara |
| 4 | 4 | Chessi |
| 5 | 9 | Fernando |

into a new-dataframe in the following format.

**New-Dataframe:**

| Person-ID | Reference-ID | Member1 | Member2 | Member3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Max | Kevin | Sara |
| 4 | 4 | Chessi |  |  |
| 5 | 9 | Fernando |  |  |

My solution would be:

1. Write all the Reference-IDs from the old-dataframe into the new-dataframe
2. Write all the Person-Ids from the old-dataframe into the new-dataframe, which their reference_id is not in the old-dataframe (see example Fernando)
3. Loop trough the "old"-dataframe and add the name to the corresponding line in the new dataframe

Do you have any suggestions, on how to make this faster/simpler?

PS: The old-dataframe can be made like this

```
person_id = [1,2,3,4,5]
reference_id = [1,1,1,4,9]
name = ['Max','Kevin','Sara',"Chessi","Fernando"]
list_tuples=list(zip(person_id,reference_id,name))
old_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(list_tuples,columns=['Person_ID','Reference_id','Name'])
```

Comment: Add a line between your text and table.

Comment: Hello Kevin, instead of or in addition to creating a table in your question, it's more useful to provide python code to create an example dataframe, so that the community can work with your  data to solve the problem

Comment: First 2 columns are always same in ouput? Is this [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: thanks everbody for the comments. I hope with the given code and the additional example of Fernando, it is more clear now. @jezrael No, the first columns don't need to be the same, since the person with the reference ID is not necessarily included in the old-dataframe (see Fernando as example)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pivot_table()` like this:

```
df1= pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Reference-ID'], values=['Person-ID', 'Name'], aggfunc=({'Person-ID':'min', 'Name':lambda x:list(x), 'Person-ID':'min'}))

df1.reset_index()[['Person-ID','Reference-ID']].join(pd.DataFrame(df1.Name.tolist()))
```

**Output:**

| Person-ID | Reference-ID | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Max | Kevin | Sara |
| 4 | 4 | Chessi | None | None |
| 5 | 9 | Fernando | None | None |

---

You can reassign column names like this:

```
df2=df1.reset_index()[['Person-ID','Reference-ID']].join(pd.DataFrame(df1.Name.tolist()))

df2.columns=list(df2.columns[0:2])+[f"Member{x+1}" for x in df2.columns[2:]]
```

Output:

| Person-ID | Reference-ID | Member1 | Member2 | Member3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Max | Kevin | Sara |
| 4 | 4 | Chessi | None | None |
| 5 | 9 | Fernando | None | None |